# Stop escaping special characters when saving to XML with DOM

Tags: java, html, xml

Is there any way to prevent Java from escaping the special characters when writing to XML using DOM?  I can’t change the format of the XML so I can’t save them in CDATA tags.

I’m trying to save HTML inside a XML file using DOM. Currently it is escaping the special characters so `<p>` is being saved as `&lt;p&gt;`.

```java
public void updateXML(Document doc) throws XPathExpressionException{
  Node aNode = getXMLNode("//PRECISSCHE.HTM/html/body", doc);
  removeChilds(aNode);
  aNode.setTextContent(saved_precis_Scheme);    
}
```

It's outputting as:

```xml
<PRECISSCHE.HTM>
    <html>
        <body>&lt;p&gt;schemeName&lt;/p&gt;</body>
    </html>
</PRECISSCHE>
```

but I need:

```xml
<PRECISSCHE.HTM>
    <html>
        <body><p>schemeName</p></body>
    </html>
</PRECISSCHE>
```

Here is my code to create the doc object:

```java
  //pull data and write to XML
    public void updateXML(String path) throws XPathExpressionException{
          try {                
              String filepath = path;
              DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
              docFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
              DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
              Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

              Tab_Client.updateClientXML(doc);

              if(!polType.equals("Household")){
                  Tab_Vehicle.updateVehicleXML(doc);
                  Tab_PCClaimsConv.updateXML(doc);
                  Tab_precis.updateXML(doc);
              }
              if(polType.equals("Household")){
                  Tab_PropertyDetails.updatePropertyDetailsXML(doc);
                  Tab_HCsumInsured.updateXML(doc);
                  Tab_Contents.updateXML(doc);
                  Tab_HCClaims.updateXML(doc);
              }

              TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
              Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
              DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
              StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
              transformer.transform(source, result);
          } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
              pce.printStackTrace();
          } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
              tfe.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
              ioe.printStackTrace();
          } catch (SAXException sae) {
              sae.printStackTrace();
          }
   }
```

Comment: Is `saved_precis_Scheme` a string containing `<p>`? And do you want to add an XML element `p` as the child of `aNode`?

Comment: If you want to save the HTML code as the content of the XML element, then it is correct it is saved as `&lt;` and such. If you want to add other XML elements to your XML element you use different methods like `createElement()` and `insertAfter` (or whatever you want to do). Please [edit] your question to include the XML content you have and how you want to change it. Also include the full source code you have as a [mcve].

Comment: saved_precis_scheme will hold some HTML. For example <p>a word</p>. Sometime it will be more complected HTML. I understand that its correct to escape the special characters but I need to disable it. I didn't design the XML and it has to store the HTML in XML without CDATA.

Comment: That's a property of your DOM to XML serialization code, which will by default generate XML that when parsed back will produce the same DOM as you started with. Since that's not what you want. you will need to override or write your own serializer. As it stands you've not posted your serialization code at all. Note that if your embedded html is not XML well-formed, you will end up with a file that is not XML.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks Alohci. I've update with the code Im using to read in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can that do 
`stringString.replaceAll("&lt;","<").replaceAll("&gt;",">")`
before you output the data